# How to persist editable Dash table populated with button

Tags: python, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I have a page in a dash app where users will fetch data from a database and visualize them on a DataTable.
The fetching process is time consuming, so I want it to be actively triggered and the fetched data to persist if a user move around the app or refresh the page.
Hence, the button (`fetch-data-button`) is connected to a store element (`data-storage`), which is then used to populate the table (`data-table`).
Both the `data-storage` and `data-table` objects persist in session (and the data table has `persistence_props = data` specified). Nonetheless, upon page refresh the table is empty again.
Am I doing something wrong?
I understand that the callback doesn't fire as the page is refreshed since the input argument (store, data) is unchanged but why is the table content not persisting?

```
import dash
from dash import Dash, html, dcc, dash_table, Input, Output, State, callback, ctx
from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate
import pandas as pd
dash.register_page(__name__, name="Data Check")


number_clicks_fetch = 0

layout = html.Div(
    children=[
        dcc.Loading(id='loading_datatable',children=[
            html.Div(children=[
                html.H1(children='Data check'),
                dash_table.DataTable(
                    # data populated with callback
                    # columns populated with callback
                    persistence=True,
                    persisted_props =['columns.name', 'data'],
                    persistence_type='session',
                    virtualization=True,
                    id='data-table'
                ),

        dcc.Store(id='data-storage', storage_type='session'),
        
        html.Button('Fetch data', id='fetch-data-button', n_clicks=number_clicks_fetch)   
    ], style={'width': '100%', 'height':'100%'},
            )
            ],
    type='circle')
])
# fetch data if button clicked. Requires settings args
@callback(Output('data-storage', 'data'),
             Input('fetch-data-button', 'n_clicks'),
             Input('global-input-arg-store', 'data'),
             )
def fetch_data(clicks, input_arg):
    if clicks == 0:
        raise PreventUpdate
    else:
        # data = slow_function(input_arg)
        # next line is for reproducibility purposes
        data=pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[12,22,32]],columns=['a','b','c'])
        return data.to_dict('records') 
    

    # if storage is updated, update table
@callback([Output('data-table','data'), 
            Output('data-table','columns'), 
            Output('data-table','fixed_rows')],
            Input('data-storage', 'data'))
def refresh_table(data):
    if data is None:
        raise PreventUpdate
    else:
        columns = [{'id': key, 'name': key, "deletable": False, "selectable": True} for key in data[0]]
    return [data, columns, {'headers': True}]
```

**EDIT**

Made a one page application that reproduces the intended behaviour.
You can see that version one does not reproduce the problem and refreshing the page triggers the callback and populates the table again using the data stored in `data-storage`. Note that the table does not have persistence set to True.

**Version 1**

```
import dash
from datetime import date
from dash import Dash, html, dcc, dash_table, Input, Output, State, callback, ctx
from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate
import pandas as pd
app = Dash(__name__)


number_clicks_fetch = 0

app.layout = html.Div(
    children=[
        dcc.Loading(id='loading_datatable',children=[
            html.Div(children=[
                html.H1(children='Data check'),
                dash_table.DataTable(
                    # data populated with callback
                    # columns populated with callback
                    # persistence=True,
                    # persisted_props =['columns.name', 'data'],
                    # persistence_type='session',
                    virtualization=True,
                    id='data-table'
                ),

        dcc.Store(id='data-storage', storage_type='session'),
        dcc.Store(id='global-input-arg-store', storage_type='session'),
        html.Button('Fetch data', id='fetch-data-button', n_clicks=number_clicks_fetch)   
    ], style={'width': '100%', 'height':'100%'},
            )
            ],
    type='circle')
])
# fetch data if button clicked. Requires settings args
@callback(Output('data-storage', 'data'),
             Input('fetch-data-button', 'n_clicks'),
             State('global-input-arg-store', 'data'),
             )
def fetch_data(clicks, input_arg):
    if clicks == 0:
        raise PreventUpdate
    else:
        # data = slow_function(input_arg)
        # next line is for reproducibility purposes
        data=pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[12,22,32]],columns=['a','b','c'])
        return data.to_dict('records') 
    

    # if storage is updated, update table
@callback([Output('data-table','data'), 
            Output('data-table','columns'), 
            Output('data-table','fixed_rows')],
            Input('data-storage', 'data'))
def refresh_table(data):
    if data is None:
        raise PreventUpdate
    else:
        print('populating table')
        columns = [{'id': key, 'name': key, "deletable": False, "selectable": True} for key in data[0]]
    return [data, columns, {'headers': True}]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Version 2, does replicate the behaviour. The data is lost upon refreshing the page as `data-storage` does not persist. Setting the persistence properties of the table is not sufficient to preserve the table.
**Version 2**

```
import dash
from datetime import date
from dash import Dash, html, dcc, dash_table, Input, Output, State, callback, ctx
from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate
import pandas as pd
app = Dash(__name__)


number_clicks_fetch = 0

app.layout = html.Div(
    children=[
        dcc.Loading(id='loading_datatable',children=[
            html.Div(children=[
                html.H1(children='Data check'),
                dash_table.DataTable(
                    # data populated with callback
                    # columns populated with callback
                    persistence=True,
                    persisted_props =['columns.name', 'data'],
                    persistence_type='session',
                    virtualization=True,
                    id='data-table'
                ),

        dcc.Store(id='data-storage'),
        dcc.Store(id='global-input-arg-store', storage_type='session'),
        html.Button('Fetch data', id='fetch-data-button', n_clicks=number_clicks_fetch)   
    ], style={'width': '100%', 'height':'100%'},
            )
            ],
    type='circle')
])
# fetch data if button clicked. Requires settings args
@callback(Output('data-storage', 'data'),
             Input('fetch-data-button', 'n_clicks'),
             State('global-input-arg-store', 'data'),
             )
def fetch_data(clicks, input_arg):
    if clicks == 0:
        raise PreventUpdate
    else:
        # data = slow_function(input_arg)
        # next line is for reproducibility purposes
        data=pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[12,22,32]],columns=['a','b','c'])
        return data.to_dict('records') 
    

    # if storage is updated, update table
@callback([Output('data-table','data'), 
            Output('data-table','columns'), 
            Output('data-table','fixed_rows')],
            Input('data-storage', 'data'))
def refresh_table(data):
    if data is None:
        print('no data')
        raise PreventUpdate
    else:
        print('populating table')
        columns = [{'id': key, 'name': key, "deletable": False, "selectable": True} for key in data[0]]
    return [data, columns, {'headers': True}]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: With button, I think maybe you should try `State('global-input-arg-store', 'data')` instead of `Input('global-input-arg-store', 'data')`

Comment: @hoatran Thanks! You are indeed correct, that should not trigger to the callback.

Comment: Did `State(...)` solve your problem?

Comment: @Hamzah Nope, I was not expecting it to solve it. I think that is a separate issue

Comment: @CAPSLOCK: but I did not see `global-input-arg-store` in your layout, maybe you are missing it.

Comment: Could you please re-run your code, and copy and paste the last version of your code? Because I tried it on my machine, it did not work and there are some IDs missing and errors.

Comment: `global-input-arg-store` lives on the main (app.py). This is required to use an element across pages. I will modify the snippet to create a one page app that replicate the issue @hoatran @hamzah

Comment: Ok, we are waiting.

Comment: @Hamzah see the two new samples, you should now be able to run the script